# C++ Printing Contents of array backwards One incorrect digit

Tags: c++, arrays

As part of a program I'm trying to print the contents of an array in reverse order. It is working fine except for one value and I can't figure out why.

I haven't gotten onto functions yet so I haven't used them in my code here is the snippet

```
case 7:
    for (int i = 11; i != -1; i--)// The variable i is initialised to 11. While i is not equal to -1 decrement i by 1.
    {
        infile >> list[i];//Read in values for array from data.dat
        cout << list[i] << " ";// Outputting the array in reverse order.
        outfile << "The array in reverse order is: " << list[i] << " " << endl;// Outputting the array in reverse order to file.

    }
    cout << endl;
    break;
```

The array is filled with the following numbers

> 8 16 12 6 16 4 8 10 2 16 12 6

The expected output is:

> 6 12 16 2 10 8 4 16 6 12 16 8

The output I'm getting is:

> 6 12 16 2 10 8 4 16 6 12 6 8

Any help appreciated

Comment: That code makes no sense at all - for each iteration of the loop you read an element then write it to standard out and a file, with no reversing of anything. You need to provide an SSCCE.

Comment: The array list is of size [12]. I'm outputting it backwards by starting at 11 and decrementing by 1 on each iteration. How does that not make sense. I've indicated the contents of the array and the output I'm getting.

Comment: Because each time round the loop you read something then write what you just read.

Comment: Yes but it's being read from the end. Why would so much of the output be correct otherwise? Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I simply don't believe that code produces that output. If you show a real, complete, self-contained example it might be possible for someone to figure out where the problem is.

Comment: I understand what you mean now. The program gives me the correct output only when I manually insert the contents of the array and not read it from the file. How would you suggest I get around this. ie. how do I fill the contents of the array with the file and also get the loop to work backwards.

Comment: Two loops - one to read the whole array, then another one to write it out backwards.

Answer (score 0):

The right way to reverse an iterator is to shift it down by one.

**Forward:**

```
T a[N];

for (std::size_t i = 0; i != N; ++i)
{
    consume(a[i]);
}
```

**Backward:**

```
T a[N];

for (std::size_t i = 0; i != N; ++i)
{
    std::size_t const ri = N - i - 1;
    //                           ^^^

    consume(a[ri]);
}
```

You *can* write a loop where you actually decrement the loop variable directly, but it's awkward since you either have to use signed integers or otherwise do an additional `- 1` when using the index, and it's altogether unnatural, hard to read and easy to get wrong. I'd much rather recommend always using the forward-moving loop as shown here and compute the reverse iterator separately.

Incidentally, this logic is already encapsulated in the iterator wrapper `std::reverse_iterator`, which is build from a normal, bidirectional moving iterator but decrements by one when being dereferenced. You can either reverse a sequence yourself by using [`make_reverse_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/make_reverse_iterator), or by using the free `rbegin`/`rend` functions:

```
#include <iterator>

T a[N];

for (auto rit = std::crbegin(a); rit != std::crend(a); ++rit)
{
    consume(*rit);
}
```